# Can I front an adverbial phrase like "high among the clouds"?

Tags: grammar, subjects, sentence-starts, noun-phrases, locative-inversion

While writing a fantasy narration I created this sentence:

> High among the clouds a castle floated.

My American friend tells me it sounds bad to a native ear. I think he sees a problem with the unusual word order.

At the same time the Hobbit starts with:

> In a hole in the ground there lived a hobbit.

...which seems a similar sentence.

**What is the science behind the word order in an English sentence?**

---

UPDATE: The original sentence was actually

> High among the clouds a castle floated, disregarding the force of gravity.

I removed the ending phrase to simplify the problem, but from some of the responses I infer that the phrase may actually matter.

Comment: Doesn't sound 'bad' to me. To exactly parallel 'The Hobbit', you could even say _High among the clouds there floated a castle_.

Comment: Ask your friends to be more precise what's wrong with it. This seems a literary issue not a grammar one.

Comment: Putting the subject at the end of a sentence is unusual in conversation.  It's not that unusual in storytelling.

Comment: @StuartF Is this site only for grammar issues and not literary ones? Sorry for lack of precision, I'm working with what I got.

Comment: Inversion **like that is considered literary**.

Comment: Sentence sounds 'off' to me. High is not necessary. Not wild about 'among the clouds'. Perhaps just, "Upon the clouds a castle floated."

Comment: @StuartF Style and grammar are intimately related! The difference between good and bad style is often down to the grammar!

Comment: Clouds are high, also high is relative, I imagine that is the source of your friend’s bad ness.  “Among the clouds”, or “High above the earth, among the clouds” would probably sound better.

Comment: First it was closed for being proofreading. Now it's been closed for being opinion-based. I don't really agree with either of these reasons, but I don't see how this is opinion-based. You can close ***almost any*** question about grammar for being opinion-based, because there are always people who use non-standard grammar and will disagree with you.

Comment: @PeterShor Yes, what an excruciating embarrassment.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot write you an answer because this question has been closed. The real answer to your question is  this: English does not like to have indefinite NPs like *a castle* as subjects. It makes sentences difficult to process. Instead we like to put old familiar information first and new exciting info at the end. And this problem is doubly bad if the indefinite NP is right at the beginning of a piece of writing. Luckily, we have (at least) three ways to get round this problem: existential clauses, subject-dependent inversion,  adjunct pre-posing.

Comment: All of these serve to delay the appearance of the indefinite NP, and ideally promote it to the end position where it will receive the most prominence. In your sentence, you've used preposed the locative adjunct but failed to promote the indefinite NP to the stellar position not deserves. As the indefinite NP precedes the verb phrase, we expect an interesting and elaborate one (otherwise why not put the NP at the end!), however we're left just with a boring intransitive verb *floated*.   Big flop. If you'd had a long VP, it would have been ok: "Above the clouds floated a castle bedecked with ..

Comment: ... dragons from all four corners of the kingdom" would work, for example. **Executive summary:** when you use existential clauses or prepose your locative adjuncts, put your indefinite NP subject at the end of the clause. That's what these constructions are there for!

Comment: Note that what Tolkien did was to combine two of these constructions. He used locative inversion to put the indefinite NP *a hobbit* at the end and also an existential clause (*there*-inseertion) to delay it even further. Very satisfying.

Comment: **NB: None of this is a matter of opinion!**

Comment: @Araucaria-Him The OP's explicit question is writing advice "What is the problem with my sentence?", definitely off topic. If it were asking about the acceptability of non SVO and the stylistic implications, then it would be totally on-topic.

Comment: @Mitch I asked "What is the problem with my sentence?" but my sentence has very particular characteristics. I would name them if I had more knowledge about English language. Can't we extend the question to make it valid? Today I learned so much thanks to the responses to this question.

Comment: @Araucaria-Him You extended my English language horizons. 

One more question: I put the location at the beginning of the sentence to establish something I would call "the order of information discovery". I wanted the reader to first look at the clouds and only then notice the castle. Does this justify the inversion?

Comment: @Araucaria-Him BTW, the original sentence was "[High] among the clouds a castle floated, disregarding the force of gravity." I removed the ending phrase to simplify the problem, but from your example with dragons I would infer that it does matter.

Comment: Why aren't up using this: A castle floated high among the clouds. That's the point. You need a good reason for that "inversion". In short, justification for it.

Comment: I specified the reason three comments above.

Comment: @Araucaria-Him the question is reopened. Call me when (if) it gets closed again!

Comment: @Atom Thanks for the edit. Changing the question from "Is this grammatical?" or "What's wrong with my sentence?" to "What is the syntax that governs these two examples?" makes it on-topic.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It should be:

> High above the clouds floated a castle.

[See this webpage](https://www.grammaring.com/subject-verb-inversion-after-place-adverbials), which says:

> When an adverb or an adverbial expression of place comes in the initial position (at the beginning of the sentence), the subject and verb are inverted.

This isn't actually a strict rule of English grammar; your original sentence is still grammatical. However, if you want your sentences to sound mellifluous (which you do when you're imitating Tolkien and writing literary narratives), you should generally follow this rule.

Comment: Have you further endorsement for 'It should be ... ' or any for 'This [(locative inversion)] isn't actually a strict rule of English grammar', Peter? I find 'In a hole in the ground lived a hobbit' fine,  'In a hole in the ground a hobbit lived' dubious, and 'In a hole in the ground, a hobbit lived and had lived for most of his life' back to fine. Perhaps it's just the addition of the comma ... though 'In a hole in the ground, a hobbit lived' doesn't sound too hot to my ears either.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: I agree with you, but I really can't say exactly when you need to use inversion after an adverb of place.

Comment: I think you have given the OP some rather arbitrary advice.  The original sentence is formulaic. Dozens of similar sentences could be found. Here's one: https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Ogre_of_Oglefort/9BOKWPWiXncC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22high+among+the+clouds+a%22&pg=PT40&printsec=frontcover

Comment: Here's another: *High among the clouds a biplane drew away...* 
 https://www.google.com/books/edition/Fever_at_Dawn/6a7qDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22high+among+the+clouds+a%22&pg=PT7&printsec=frontcover

Comment: Here's another: *High among the clouds the wind was still racing...* https://www.google.com/books/edition/Appleton_s_Magazine/TyoiAQAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22high+among+the+clouds+the%22&pg=PA135&printsec=frontcover

Comment: "In the distance, a fully rigged ship was making good speed towards the Continent' feels like the comma is advisable but the sentence is then fine whereas 'In a house near the forest, a shepherd lived' feels off. I think it might be because 'live in a house' is more of a colligation than 'make good speed in the distance'

Comment: @TimR 'High among the clouds was still racing the wind' sounds awful. I think locative inversion only works with simple present and simple past.

Comment: Probably what makes the shepherd example sound odd to your ears is that the storytelling formula requires "... *there lived* a shepherd".

Comment: @EdwinAshworth  You're making my point. Peter is the one recommending subject-verb inversion.  The line reads "... the wind was still racing"

Comment: 'High above the clouds floated a castle' is certainly ideal for the obvious literary genre involved. But 'High above the clouds[,] a castle floated serenely yet imposingly' resists inversion.

Comment: @TimR: It's not entirely arbitrary. None of your examples should be inverted.  *"High above the clouds was floating a castle* (which parallels your first example) sounds awful. So does *High above the clouds drew away a biplane* and *High above the clouds was still racing the wind.* As Edwin Ashforth says, Yyu should only use inversion with simple present and simple past, and even then only with sentences that have relatively simple structures.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Peter TimR See my answer in the comments under the question. The reason those other examples of TimR's are ok is that they have long VPs. The OP's example and Edwin's shepherd sentence both have one-word intransitive ones. These boring VPs shouldn't be promoted to the star position  in the sentence, especially when we're already using a construction whose very purpose is to promote an indefinite NP to the end of the sentence where it can shine.

Comment: @PeterShor: I wouldn't even go as far as to say "*should* be inverted" but that inversion is *licensed*. There's nothing ungrammatical or stylistically flawed with *Down the hill the children rolled*.

Comment: @Araucaria-Him  Even a sentient lobster knows that verb phrases aren't boring.

Comment: @TimR Single-word intransitive VPs can be boring, which is why other words like to skip over them all the time. Your "*Down the hill the children rolled*" has a definite NP, which is why it works. "Rolled" is the only new info in the sentence.